# How can we rectify nan while using trigonometric functions in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, error-handling, nan, trigonometry

```
    cout << "Please enter the A vector's magnitude \n";
    cin >> A_v;
    cout << "Please enter the B vector's magnitude \n";
    cin >> B_v;
    cout << "The general form to find the direction of the resultant vector = \n" << "tan^-1 X " << UL << " [B X sin] \n" << UL_
    << "        [A + B X cos]\n";
    cout << "Please enter the angle value \n";
    cin >> ct;
    cost = cos(ct);
    sint = sin(ct);
    itan = atan(ct);
    al = itan*((B*sint)/(A+(B*cost)));
    ald = al*(180/3.141562);
    cout << "The direction of the vector is inclined at " << ald << " degrees \n";
```

This is a program to find the inclination/direction of a vector(in physics)

Comment: I get the 'nan' error while i use that trigonometric functions

Comment: What do you mean by "rectify nan", specifically?

Comment: do you input radians or degrees?

Comment: also, using atan(angle) does not seem correct

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I want the numerical value as answer and not 'nan' as the answer

Comment: @SvenNilsson I get input in degrees
I just referred to the net for tan inverse and got to know that using atan we may get tan inverse, is using atan() is incorrect

Comment: Well, there is no numerical value to give as an answer, that's why the result of the calculation is a nan. Unfortunately, since the shown code fails to meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre], there's not really anything else anyone will be able to tell you.

Comment: `cos` and `sin` expect their parameter to be an angle in radians, not degrees. If you have the angle in degrees, you need to convert it to radians first, before calling those functions. `atan` doesn't expect an angle as a parameter at all - passing an angle to it, whether in degrees or radians, doesn't make any sense. A formula that expects you to compute `atan(some_angle)` can't possibly be right.